# How change ID in HLS origin manifest?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm using Nginx's RTMP module and wanted a way to change the m3u8 manifest ID.
My current setup is this:

#### Nginx config

```
hls_variant _1080p BANDWIDTH=8388608,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=8000000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,FRAME-RATE=60,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2";
hls_variant _720p BANDWIDTH=6291456,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=6000000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=60,CODECS="avc1.640028,mp4a.40.2";
hls_variant _480p BANDWIDTH=4194304,AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=4000000,RESOLUTION=848x480,FRAME-RATE=30,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2";
```

Using yt-dlp to retrieve the link information, we have:

```
ID   EXT RESOLUTION FPS │   TBR PROTO │ VCODEC      ACODEC
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4194 mp4 848x480     30 │ 4194k m3u8  │ avc1.4d401f mp4a.40.2
6291 mp4 1280x720    60 │ 6291k m3u8  │ avc1.640028 mp4a.40.2
8388 mp4 1920x1080   60 │ 8389k m3u8  │ avc1.640028 mp4a.40.2
```

But using yt-dlp on a Twitch link for example, we retrieve the following information:

```
ID               EXT RESOLUTION FPS │   TBR PROTO │ VCODEC      ACODEC     ABR
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
audio_only       mp4 audio only     │  160k m3u8  │ audio only  mp4a.40.2 160k
160p             mp4 284x160     30 │  230k m3u8  │ avc1.4D401F mp4a.40.2
360p             mp4 640x360     30 │  630k m3u8  │ avc1.4D401F mp4a.40.2
480p             mp4 852x480     30 │ 1428k m3u8  │ avc1.4D401F mp4a.40.2
720p60           mp4 1280x720    60 │ 3423k m3u8  │ avc1.4D401F mp4a.40.2
1080p60__source_ mp4 1920x1080   60 │ 9037k m3u8  │ avc1.64002A mp4a.40.2
```

My doubt is whether there is a way to change the ID column in my configuration in Nginx or this configuration is something exclusive coming from another m3u8 manifest generator software.